# Multiple certificates - Multitenant apps in IIS 8.5

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012, iis-8, multi-tenant, iis-8.5

The context:

I currently have a multitenant site (sub1.maindomain.com) and I am working on adding several other sites. Some of the new sites (sub2.maindomain.com, secdomain.com, ...)  will probably also be multitenant.

I have certificates for each site I add, but only one IP address.

I'm working on Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5.

---

The problem:

In order to allow multiple certificates I have to enable SNI in the https binding. Once I enable the SNI for the multitenant site (therefore editing the hostname) subdomains are no longer recognized (therefore no multitenancy).

Changing/Renaming/Restructuring the sub1.maindomain.com domain is not a real option, since it's being used by active clients for hosted pages among other things.

---

So far:

I am considering a wildcard certificate on which I can have the domains for all sites, (*.sub1.maindomain.com, *.maindomain.com, *.secdomain.com, ...) but I read that some browsers might have an issue with it and it is not recommended.

**EDIT: It's been confirmed to me that I cannot consider the wildcard certificate option, mainly because of the price.**

I have also tried using the Application Request Routing to solve the issue as described [here](http://pzxc.com/apache-style-wildcard-hostname-rewrite-rules-in-iis) but so far I it hasn't panned out.

From what I've tried so far I am either getting certificate errors in some or all of my sites, or "turning off" the multitenancy for the multitenant sites.

---

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have a single multitenant app we allocated a second IP, given also that the cost is acceptable. The multitenant app is on one IP, the single tenant apps are all hosted on the other IP using the SNI feature to enable the use of multiple certificates.